# Create a StorageV2 Storage account in an Azure resource management template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm attempting to create an ARM Template that includes creating a Storage account.

I want to create a `StorageV2 (general purpose v2)` account but this seems to fail because `StorageV2` does not exist in the [schema](https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json).

```
{
  "name": "[variables('xblobstorageName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
  "sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('xblobstorageType')]"
  },
  "dependsOn": [],
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "xblobstorage"
  },
  "kind": "StorageV2"
}
```

The only allowed values for `kind` are `Storage` and `BlobStorage` so when attempting to deploy the above template the following error is received:

```
"error": {
 "code": "AccountPropertyIsInvalid",
 "message": "Account property kind is invalid for the request."
}
```

Is it possible to create a V2 storage account using ARM Templates?

Comment: Can you try updateing the apiVersion to 2018-02-01

Comment: @MartinBrandl Ah of course! Feel free to make that answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure, thank you - happy I was able to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to **update** the **apiVersion** to `2018-02-01`.

I wrote a PowerShell script to determine the latest API Version for a resource provider:

```
<#
.Synopsis
   Gets the latest API version of a resource provider
.DESCRIPTION
   The following cmdlet returns the latest API version for the specified resource provider.
   You can also include pre-release (preview) versions using the -IncludePreview switch
.EXAMPLE
   Using the Full Parameter Set:
   Get-AzureRmResourceProviderLatestApiVersion -Type Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts
.EXAMPLE
   Using the Full Parameter Set with the -IncludePreview switch:
   Get-AzureRmResourceProviderLatestApiVersion -Type Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts -IncludePreview
.EXAMPLE
   Using the ProviderAndType Parameter Set:
   Get-AzureRmResourceProviderLatestApiVersion -ResourceProvider Microsoft.Storage -ResourceType storageAccounts
#>
function Get-AzureRmResourceProviderLatestApiVersion
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([string])]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Full', Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Type,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ProviderAndType', Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$ResourceProvider,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ProviderAndType', Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$ResourceType,

        [switch]$IncludePreview
    )

    # retrieving the resource providers is time consuming therefore we store
    # them in a script variable to accelerate subsequent requests.
    if (-not $script:resourceProvider)
    {
        $script:resourceProvider = Get-AzureRmResourceProvider
    }

    if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Full')
    {
        $ResourceProvider = ($Type -replace "\/.*")
        $ResourceType = ($Type -replace ".*?\/(.+)", '$1')
    }

    $provider = $script:resourceProvider |
        Where-Object {
        $_.ProviderNamespace -eq $ResourceProvider -and
        $_.ResourceTypes.ResourceTypeName -eq $ResourceType
    }

    if ($IncludePreview)
    {
        $provider.ResourceTypes.ApiVersions[0]
    }
    else
    {
        $provider.ResourceTypes.ApiVersions | Where-Object {
            $_ -notmatch '-preview'
        } | Select-Object -First 1
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Get-AzureRmResourceProviderLatestApiVersion -Type Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts
```

And wrote a blog article about it:
[Determine latest API version for a resource provider](https://about-azure.com/2018/06/12/determine-latest-api-version-for-a-resource-provider/)